# How can I pause a jQuery on mouse hover div?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery that on mouse move it fade in/fade out a `div` object like this:

```
var timer;
$(window).on('mousemove', function () {
    $("#my_div").fadeIn(1000)
    $('#my_div').addClass('show');
    try {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    } catch (e) {}
    timer = setTimeout(function () {    
        $('#my_div').fadeOut(1000,function() {   
            $(this).removeClass('show');
        });   
    }, 1960); 
});
```

The problem is that on my `div` tag I have an input form and other inputs.

How can I pause this jQuery until the mouse is hover the `my_div`?

Comment: I don't understand. If the DIV isn't visible at first, how can you hover over it?

Comment: Do you mean how do keep the timer not being started when you are hovering the div?

Comment: @Barmar simply because the div become visible on mouse move

Comment: @JonH I mean pause the timer until hover

Comment: Simone - so you want the timer to start when someone hovers the div?  Don't you think you would need a function that would check that?  Target the div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if the `event.target` is the `my_div` element or one of its descendants:

```
var timer, myDiv = $('#my_div');

$(document).on('mousemove', function(ev) {
    var _self = $(ev.target);

    clearTimeout(timer);

    if (_self.attr('id') === 'my_div' || _self.parents('#my_div').length) {
        return;
    }    

    if(!myDiv.hasClass('show')) {
       myDiv.fadeIn();
    }          

    timer = setTimeout(function() { 
        myDiv.fadeOut(1000, function() {
            myDiv.removeClass('show');
        });
    }, 1960);    
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ohyh3qsp/1/)

Comment: But why would you recommend the mousemove on the entire document?  Why wouldnt you target the div specifically?

Comment: @JonH I don't know how the OP uses the code. Maybe it's necessary to use the document although I'd also recommend to use the next static parent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var timer;
$(window).on('mousemove', function () {
    if($('#my_div:hover').length !== 0) {
         clearTimeout(timer);
         return;
    }
    $("#my_div").fadeIn(1000)
    $('#my_div').addClass('show');
    try {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    } catch (e) {}
        timer = setTimeout(function () {    
        $('#my_div').fadeOut(1000,function() {   
        $(this).removeClass('show');
    });   
  }, 1960); 
});
```

This won't stop the event, it will only cancel it in case you are moving your mouse on top of `my_div`, if you want to stop the event use `addEventListener` and then it's easy to stop it